# Apply ewm function on Pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this DataFrame

```
ddd = pd.DataFrame({'day':['m','t','m','t','m','t','m','t'] 
                    ,'val':[15,2,10,4,5,8,2,10]})
```

I want to groupby by `day` and aggregate the `val` with [ewm](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html)

If I do groupby and mean I get this

```
ddd.groupby(['day']).mean()

     val
day     
m      8
t      6
```

Now same like this if I try

```
ddd.groupby(['day']).ewm(com=1.0).mean()
```

I get error `AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'ewm'`

My expected output would look like this

```
     val
day     
m      4.733333
t      8.133333
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all `dataframe` or `series` functions are implemented for `groupby` objects. But you can use `apply` to get your expected result

```
ddd.groupby(['day']).apply(lambda x: x.ewm(com=1.0).mean().iloc[-1])
```

Out:

```
          val
day          
m    4.733333
t    8.133333
```